# Can someone explain this algorithm to me that we have pulled off from a stock market analysis and prediction web project?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-mining, stock

```
public void algo() {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Qua from Stock where Name = '" + DropDownList1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    int scount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
    con.Close();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Price from PrefStock where Stock = '" + DropDownList1.Text+"'",con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    double amt = Convert.ToDouble(dr[0].ToString());
    con.Close();

    int count = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);

    double per = (count * 100);
    per = per / scount;

    double rate = getCompStocks(DropDownList1.Text);

    int a1 = 0, a2 = 1;
    int b1 = 1, b2 = 3;
    int c1 = 3, c2 = 5;
    int d1 = 5, d2 = 10;
    int e1 = 10, e2 = 15;
    int f1 = 15, f2 = 25;
    int g1 = 25, g2 = 50;
    int h1 = 50, h2 = 75;
    int i1 = 75, i2 = 100;

    double range = 0;

    if (a2 >= per && per > a1)
    {
        range = 0.05;
    }
    else if (b2 >= per && per > b1)
    {
        range = 0.10;
    }
    else if (c2 >= per && per > c1)
    {
        range = 0.50;
    }
    else if (d2 >= per && per > d1)
    {
        range = 0.75;
    }
    else if (e2 >= per && per > e1)
    {
        range = 1;
    }
    else if (f2 >= per && per > f1)
    {
        range = 1.5;
    }
    else if (g2 >= per && per > g1)
    {
        range = 3;
    }
    else if (h2 >= per && per > h1)
    {
        range = 6;
    }
    else if (i2 >= per && per > i1)
    {
        range = 10;
    }

    double frate = range * rate * 2;

    double price = amt * frate;
    price = price + amt; 

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PrefStock Set Price = '" + price + "' Where Stock = '" + DropDownList1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PreferredStocks Set StockPrice = '" + price + "' Where StockName = '" + DropDownList1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

We pulled this code from a web app project that will show a expected price of a stock from the previously entered inputs.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well I try to explain in "human language" with bits of code :D. So orthodox hardcode guys sorry.

**Step 1)** To database you send demand to return specific data according to what is choosed in *DropDownList1* and read them and that is *scount*

**Step 2)** Code get another data, read it, and from *dr[0].ToString()* it do *amt* variable. (dr[0] is name from you want to take data and that in [] is index.

- Easy example in array of numbers (int[] myArray) you have these
  numbers {0,1,2,3,4}. If you call myArray[3] you will get number 3.
  Indexes here are ZERO BASED. So you have no 1 2 3 4 5, but 0 1 2 3 4
  5.

**Step 3)** From what is in *TextBox3* it do *count*

**Step 4)** Make a *per* from the *count* and *scount* I believe this is (should be) clear.

**Step 5)** You have that bunch of ints (it is standard int variable, you can do it like that if you have some similararities (it just a have logic in that code)
(E.g.  `int a1 = 0, a2 = 1;` is the same as (below), it is only space saver...:

```
int a1 = 0;
int a2 = 1;
```

**Step 6)** You compare number from those a1,a2 to i1,i2 where it take first condition what will pass (so if it pass in part *else if (f2 >= per && per > f1)* then it will not process those next. It will say ok, here it is. Condition is ok. We are done.

**Step 7)** Process those data in the new variables *frate* and *price* variables and update data in the database.

I believe everything should be clear.